# Laravel multiple select option (checkbox and radio button) save to pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables: `questions`, `participants`, `choices`, and `choice_participant` (pivot table). I displayed the questions with their choices on the user's page (I used the radio box to select an option) and saved it to the table `choice_participant`.

Sample table for "participants".

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Philip Cruz |
| 3 | Mary Anne |

Sample table for "questions"

| id | question | question_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Question # 01 | single_select |
| 2 | Question # 02 | multiple_select |
| 3 | Question # 03 | single_select |

Sample table for "choices"

| id | question_id | choice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Choice 01 |
| 2 | 1 | Choice 02 |
| 3 | 1 | Choice 03 |
| 4 | 2 | Choice 04 |
| 5 | 2 | Choice 05 |
| 6 | 2 | Choice 06 |

Sample table for "choice_participant (pivot table)"

| id | participant_id | choice_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |

Blade display

```
@if($question->question_type == 'single_select')
   @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
      <input id="choices[{{$question->id}}]" type="radio" value="{{$choice->id}}" name="choices[{{$question->id}}]">
      <label for="choices[{{$question->id}}]">{{ $choice->choice }}</label>
   @endforeach

@else
   @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
      <input id="choices[{{$question->id}}]" type="checkbox" value="{{$choice->id}}" name="choices[{{$question->id}}]">
      <label for="choices[{{$question->id}}]">{{ $choice->choice }}</label>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Controller to save to pivot

```
foreach ($request->choices as $key => $choice_value) {
    $choices =  $participant->choices()->attach($choice_value);
}
```

This saves perfectly if the question type is "single_select," but in "multiple_select," it saves only one choice. I need to save all the selected choices in the checkbox in the pivot table. Hoping for your help, experts.

Here is the [Actual UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fGHh.png)

I am expecting to save all the choices that the user selected in "single_select (radio button)" and all selected options in "multiple_select (checkbox).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have multiple "values" posted from a HTML form (checkboxes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355330/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-values-posted-from-a-html-form-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your Blade template:

```html
@if($question->question_type == 'single_select')
    @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
        <input id="choice_{{$choice->id}}" type="radio" value="{{$choice->id}}" name="choices[{{$question->id}}]">
        <label for="choice_{{$choice->id}}">{{ $choice->choice }}</label>
    @endforeach

@else
    @foreach($question->choices as $choice)
        <input id="choice_{{$choice->id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{$choice->id}}" name="choices[{{$question->id}}][]">
        <label for="choice_{{$choice->id}}">{{ $choice->choice }}</label>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Notice the `[]` after the `name` attribute for checkboxes. This allows multiple values to be sent for the same name.

in your controller, you need to handle these arrays properly. When saving the choices

```php
foreach ($request->choices as $question_id => $choice_values) {
    if (is_array($choice_values)) {
        foreach ($choice_values as $choice_value) {
            $participant->choices()->attach($choice_value);
        }
    } else {
        $participant->choices()->attach($choice_values);
    }
}
```

This change will ensure that all selected choices for `multiple_select` questions are properly saved in the `choice_participant` table.